# (Interface) A circular dependency was detected for the service of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have 2 interfaces:

```
public interface IPedidoService
{
    UsuarioDrogueria CUsuarioDrogueria(string userId, int idDrogueria);
    List<PedidoComboProducto> CPedidosCombosProductos(int idcombo, int idPedido);  
} 

public interface IEmailService
{
    void SendEmailAttachment(string email, string subject, string archive);
    void SendNotificationEmail(List<Pedido> pedidos, string email, Drogueria drog);
    void SendNotificationEmailADM(Pedido pedido) ;
}
```

I want to use the functions from `IEmailService` inside `IPedidoService`, so I inject it in its constructor when I create the respository.

```
public class PedidoService : IPedidoService
{
    private readonly IEmailService emailService;

    public PedidoService(IEmailService e)
    {
        this.emailService = e;
    }
}
```

Up until here everything works fine, but when I try to do reverse the roles (`IPedidoService` functions inside `IEmailService`):

```
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    private readonly IPedidoService pedidoSettings;

    public EmailService(IPedidoService p)
    {
        this.pedidoSettings = p;
    }
}
```

I end up getting this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A circular dependency was detected for the service of type
   'EnvioPedidos.Data.Abstract.IPedidoService'.
    EnvioPedidos.Data.Abstract.IPedidoService(EnvioPedidos.PedidoService) ->
    EnvioPedidos.Data.Abstract.IEmailService(EnvioPedidos.EmailService) ->
    EnvioPedidos.Data.Abstract.IPedidoService
```

Can anybody help me trace the issue here?

Comment: That appears to be a good exception message. To create an instance of `PedidoService`, the DI container needs to create an instance of `EmailService`. To create an instance of `EmailService`, it needs to create an instance of `PedidoService`. Which one of those can it create first?

Comment: Or to make it clearer, take the DI container out of this and try to create instances of PedidoService and EmailService yourself.

Comment: What about using lazy loading?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple way is to use `Lazy<T>` class which is based on this [blog](https://thomaslevesque.com/2020/03/18/lazily-resolving-services-to-fix-circular-dependencies-in-net-core/):

Custom extension method:

```
public static class LazyResolutionMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddLazyResolution(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services.AddTransient(
            typeof(Lazy<>),
            typeof(LazilyResolved<>));
    }
}

public class LazilyResolved<T> : Lazy<T>
{
    public LazilyResolved(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        : base(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>)
    {
    }
}
```

Configure in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{           
    //services.AddSingleton<IPedidoService, PedidoService>();
    //services.AddSingleton<IEmailService, EmailService>();

    services.AddLazyResolution();
}
```

Change your implements class:

```
public class PedidoService : IPedidoService
{
    private readonly Lazy<IEmailService> emailService;

    public PedidoService(Lazy<IEmailService> e)
    {
        this.emailService = e;
    }

    //...
}
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    private readonly Lazy<IPedidoService> pedidoSettings;

    public EmailService(Lazy<IPedidoService> p)
    {
        this.pedidoSettings = p;
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have 2 classes, they cannot reference each other by dependency injection. This is called a circular dependency, as shown by your error. You need a 3rd class that references both services and you can use the methods there.

```
public class PedidoService
{
    public PedidoService()
    {

    }
}

public class EmailService
{

    public EmailService()
    {

    }
}

public class Container
{
    private readonly EmailService emailService;
    private readonly PedidoService pedidoService;

    public Container(EmailService emailService, PedidoService pedidoService)
    {
        this.emailService = emailService;
        this.pedidoService = pedidoService;
    }
    //use the services here
}
```