# .Net Core custom logger circular dependency injection reference / infinite loop

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, .net-core, dependency-injection, ilogger

I tried to write a customer ILogger / ILoggerProvider that has a dependency on a service that has a dependency on ILogger :)  That leaves me with a circular reference and an infinite loop.

How could I modify this code to avoid the circular reference?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IDependentOnLoggerService, MyService>();

            serviceCollection.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
            });

            serviceCollection.AddCustomLogger();

            using (var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider())
            {
                var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
                var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();

                logger.LogInformation("hello world");
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IDependentOnLoggerService
    {
        void DoWork();
    }

    public class MyService : IDependentOnLoggerService
    {
        private ILogger logger;

        public MyService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            this.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyService>();
            this.logger.LogInformation("MyService create");
        }

        public void DoWork()
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation("Doing work");
        }
    }

    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static void AddCustomLogger(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddCustomLogger();
            });
        }

        private static ILoggingBuilder AddCustomLogger(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
        {
            if (builder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
            }

            builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider, CustomLoggerProvider>(
                serviceProvider =>
                {
                    // this causes circulation dependency injection, resolving IDependentOnLoggerService will try to resolve an ILogger which will bring it right back here
                    var loggerDependentService = serviceProvider.GetService<IDependentOnLoggerService>(); 

                    return new CustomLoggerProvider(loggerDependentService);
                }));

            return builder;
        }
    }

    public class CustomLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        IDependentOnLoggerService dependentOnLoggerService;

        public CustomLoggerProvider(IDependentOnLoggerService dependentOnLoggerService)
        {
            this.dependentOnLoggerService = dependentOnLoggerService;
        }

        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        {
            return new CustomLogger(this.dependentOnLoggerService);
        }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }

    public class CustomLogger : ILogger
    {
        IDependentOnLoggerService dependentOnLoggerService;

        public CustomLogger(IDependentOnLoggerService dependentOnLoggerService)
        {
            this.dependentOnLoggerService = dependentOnLoggerService;
        }

        public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
            this.dependentOnLoggerService.DoWork();
            Console.WriteLine(state.ToString());
        }
    }
```

If possible, I'd like to keep the structure similar and not rewrite with a generic host and IHostBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a third class to reference both services, and you only need to dependency inject this class where you need the service in it.

A similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217815/interface-a-circular-dependency-was-detected-for-the-service-of-type/62254531#62254531), you can take a look.